# Changing data on click button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have some functionalities within some GameObjects.
These functionalities need to be changed when an upgrade is purchased within the game. The problem is that each function is set on its own object.

The first problem is that the variables don't change when I click on the button. As you can see I have added an onclick value to the button, stating that when the button is clicked. The value should change.

[image: Button UI]

The problem here is that ***"Object reference not set to an instance"***

The second problem I face is that each projectile is fired independently. So if I change the static damage of 1 it won't be transferred to other projectiles.

UpgradeMenu

```
﻿using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class UpgradeMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Text accuracyText;

    [SerializeField]
    private Text speedText;

    [SerializeField]
    private Text damageText;

    [SerializeField]
    private float accuracyMultiplier = 0.7f;

    private Weapon weapon;
    private Projectile projectile;
    private Player player;

    void OnEnable()
    {
        UpdateValues();
    }

    void UpdateValues ()
    {
      accuracyText.text = weapon.randomAngle.ToString();
      damageText.text = projectile.DamageOnHit.ToString();
      speedText.text = player.MaxRun.ToString();

    }

    public void UpgradeAccuracy ()
    {
      weapon.randomAngle = (int)weapon.randomAngle * accuracyMultiplier;
      UpdateValues();
    }

    public void UpgradeDamage ()
    {
      projectile.DamageOnHit = (int)projectile.DamageOnHit + 1;
      UpdateValues();
    }
}
```

Projectile (DamageScript)

```
﻿using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

//[RequireComponent (typeof(Rigidbody2D))]
public class Projectile : MonoBehaviour {

    [Header ("Speed")]
    public float baseSpeed;
    public float randomSpeed;
    public Vector2 SpeedV2;
    public Vector2 Direction;

    [Header ("Damage")]
    public int DamageOnHit;

    [Header ("Layers")]
    public LayerMask solid_layer;
    public LayerMask entities_layer;

    [Header ("OnHit FX")]
    public GameObject HitFxPrefab;
    public GameObject DustFxPrefab;

    [Header ("Bounce")]
    public bool BounceOnCollide = false;
    public int bouncesLeft = 0;

    [HideInInspector]
    public Health owner; // owner of the projectile
    private Vector2 Position; // Current position
    private Vector2 movementCounter = Vector2.zero;  // Counter for subpixel movement
    public BoxCollider2D myCollider; 
    List<Health> healthsDamaged = new List<Health>(); // List to store healths damaged

    void OnCollideWith (Collider2D col, bool horizontalCol = true) {
        var component = col.GetComponent<Health> ();
        // If the target the hitbox collided with has a health component and it is not our owner and it is not on the already on the list of healths damaged by the current hitbox
        if (component != null && component != owner && !healthsDamaged.Contains(component)) {
            // Add the health component to the list of damaged healths
            healthsDamaged.Add (component);

            // Apply the damage
            var didDamage = component.TakeDamage (DamageOnHit);
            // Destroy the projectile after applying damage
            if (didDamage) {
                DestroyMe ();
                return;
            }
        }

        // if the projectile hit's a solid object, destroy it
        if (col.gameObject.layer ==  (int)Mathf.Log(solid_layer.value, 2)) {
            DestroyMeWall ();
            return;
        }
    }

    void OnCollideWithEntity(Collider2D col) {
        var component = col.GetComponent<Health> ();
        // If the target the hitbox collided with has a health component and it is not our owner and it is not on the already on the list of healths damaged by the current hitbox
        if (component != null && component != owner && !healthsDamaged.Contains(component)) {
            // Add the health component to the list of damaged healths
            healthsDamaged.Add (component);

            // Apply the damage
            var didDamage = component.TakeDamage (DamageOnHit);
            // Destroy the projectile after applying damage
            if (didDamage) {
                DestroyMe ();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There are many null reference exception questions that could help in this situation, but it will be too difficult to track down the actual problem from this. You have an object that does exist, or a value inside the method is null. Your second issue shows no static value being changed. That's expected behavior when you change the value of a property in one object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, change

```
[Header ("Damage")]
public int DamageOnHit;
```

to static

```
public static int DamageOnHit = /*your starting value*/;
```

This ensures that all projectiles will share the same damage it deals on a hit.
For instance, if you currently have 10 projectiles in a scene, and `DamageOnHit` is 2, they all will deal 2 damage.

Without the `static`, each of the projectile will have it's own `DamageOnHit`. This brings us to the next case  too:

If each projectile had it's own `DamageOnHit`, and we want to modify `DamageOnHit`, we need to specify which projectile's damage to modify.
But if it's static, it becomes much simpler as ALL of the projectile shares the same `DamageOnHit`.

Now, if you wanted to change the `DamageOnHit` for ALL projectiles, just do

```
Projectile.DamageOnHit = /*Your new damage value*/
```

Also, your `null reference exception` occured due to the fact that you never did assign your `projectile` in `UpgradeMenu`.
(Notice how you never did `projectile = /*your projectile*/` in `UpgradeMenu.cs`?)

By default, that will make the variable null. And trying to do `null.DamageOnHit += 1` would make no sense.

**Small Edit:** Making a variable static would also mean that you can't expose it to the inspector. But you can assign a starting value like the code shown initially.

Comment: hi @Kaynn thank you for your answer! I tried adapting towards your script and I have changed the DamageOnHit to a static. I just don't understand what you mean with the following `(Notice how you never did projectile = /*your projectile*/ in UpgradeMenu.cs?)` Could you elaborate on that a bit?

Comment: @mafiaf I was stating "You never did assign your `projectile` variable, hence it became `null` by default" on that.

Comment: I'm just not sure how to assign the projectile variable. Isn't it enough to use the following`private Projectile projectile;` to gain access to all particles? Or do I have to assign projectile on a gameObject? because the gameObject only spawns when I click (shoot). So I wouldn't be able to assign it since the gameObject is not ingame.

Comment: @mafiaf Your type was `Projectile`, which could only at most store one projectile. `List<Projectile>` was what you need. Though if you really wanted access to all the projectiles, you should have a script that manages all the projectiles (spawning, destroying of projectiles). That script will then store the list of all the active projectiles which you can then use to access them.

Comment: Hi I have everything within my projectile script. I just showed a small part of it, but it instantiates a projectile, destroys it on contact and does the whole movement of it also it creates a "ProjectileMachineGun(clone)" object. So if everything of the projectile is within one script (My projectile.cs script) how am I able to assign the projectiles on to that script from within the UpgradeMenu script?

Comment: Sorry for the questions, I'm fairly new to coding in c# and unity. It's a bit hard to understand everything

Comment: I seem to have a list component within my Projectile script
`List<Health> healthsDamaged = new List<Health>();` 

Which gets added up on other parts of the script Would it be possible to use this? But it's only a list to store the health damaged.

 `void OnCollideWith (Collider2D col, bool horizontalCol = true) {
  var component = col.GetComponent<Health> ();
  if (component != null && component != owner && !healthsDamaged.Contains(component)) {
   healthsDamaged.Add (component);`

Comment: You need a static/singleton `List<Projectile>` that represents all the active projectiles, and then let `UpgradeMenu` access that list when needed.